# Find an ordering of nodes in a graph that minimizes sum of edge lengths

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, combinatorics

Input: A connected undirected graph `G` with `n` vertices.

Output: A linear ordering of the vertices `0, 1, ..., n - 1` that minimizes

`sum(j - i for i in range(n) for j in range(n) if i < j and (i, j) in G)`.

`n` may be about 1000000, and the number of edges will be a constant factor larger than `n`, around 5000000.  In a slightly more general problem, the edges may have small positive integer weights.  An exact solution is preferred, but not necessary.

One approach could be a variant of bubble sort that swaps elements if it would bring the sum down.  But I'm not sure if this algorithm would get stuck in a local minimum.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be tasked with the Minimum Linear Assignment problem. There is a PhD Thesis on that topic available online ( [Seitz, Hanna - Contributions to the
Minimum Linear Arrangement
Problem](http://archiv.ub.uni-heidelberg.de/volltextserver/10578/1/MinLA_Thesis_Seitz.pdf) ) that has an accessible exposition (see pp. 27 ff.).

The problem is NP-hard. The cited resource reports the complexity of the best known algorithm as `O(|E| * 2^|V|)` (pp. 29 ff.). It also lists classes of graphs for which efficient (polynomial) algorithms are known and discusses approximation schemes.

PS:
Not an expert here, just ran across the problem and the thesis which appears to be a good starting point.